# start_new_thread of a class inside start_new_thread

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use `start_new_thread` inside another `start_new_thread`.

Now, the rough layout of the code is like this

Main.py

```
....
a = Helper()
start_new_thread(a.x,()) # 1 
....
```

Inside Helper class

```
....
def x(self):
    start_new_thread(self.a,()) # 2
....
```

These functions are not thread safe intentionally.
The problem is that whenever the `#2` executes it is stopping the main thread temporarily until it is returned.

Why is this happening and what can be done to overcome this?

Comment: Python employs a [global interpreter lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Only one thread will ever run at any given time.

Comment: What if there is no escape from the multiple threading and I must use all those threads simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its time for you to read about the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: It so happens that the functions cannot be removed from threads. Those threads are needed as the work is network related. Removing threads would cause the main process to hang which is not desired at all

Comment: Network I/O is one of the exception where the GIL is released. But you can still do network related without threads using something like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), [greenlet](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/) or [select for the standard lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html). Also you will have better performance in case of handling many connections at time.

Answer (score 0):

```
class KThread(threading.Thread):

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.killed = False

 def start(self):

    self.__run_backup = self.run
    self.run = self.__run      # Force the Thread to install our trace.
    threading.Thread.start(self)

 def __run(self):

    sys.settrace(self.globaltrace)
    self.__run_backup()
    self.run = self.__run_backup

 def globaltrace(self, frame, why, arg):
    if why == 'call':
      return self.localtrace
    else:
      return None

 def localtrace(self, frame, why, arg):
    if self.killed:
      if why == 'line':
        raise SystemExit()
    return self.localtrace

 def kill(self):

    self.killed = True

 ###################################

class 2:
 t2 = KThread(target=function)
 t2.start()
 t2.kill()
 t3 = KThread(target=function)
 t3.start()
 t3.kill()
```